# IAM role is not assigned an instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm trying to export my table from DynamoDB to S3. Following the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html) I created the two roles needed for the pipeline, DataPipelineDefaultRole and DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole. After trying to execute the pipeline, I discovered that my DataPipelineDefaultRole was not created with an instance profile.

I've been looking through forums and Amazon says that people receive errors like this when they create their IAM Roles through the CLI. Their recommendation is to create the roles through the console and then the instance profile will be attached to the roll automatically. I'm creating the role through the console but for the DataPipelineDefaultRole, there is no instance profile attached?

Is there a way to manually attach an instance profile? Or am I missing something that is causing this to not auto-generate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

It highlights info about instance profiles and namely how to create if you already have existing roles etc. I think this might be what you're looking for.

i.e .

`aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name DataPipelineDefaultRole`

then

`aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --role-name DataPipelineDefaultRole --instance-profile-name DataPipelineDefaultRole`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21658272)

Comment: Oops, keep doing that, Updated!

Comment: This does not attach the instance profile to the role. The commands run without error but then after checking the role, there is no instance profile attached. It's odd because checking the roles attached to the instance profile using "aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name DataPipelineDefaultRole" shows the correct role as apart of the instance profile. But when I look on the console display, it still shows no instance profile on the role.

Comment: I think that’s to do with how the roles are created, generally you can only see instance profile ARN’s if you created the role to “Allow EC2 to call services on your behalf”, it’s a mystery why some things only show up inside Console but others hidden into CLI/API calls.

Answer (score 1):

I have test the solution by Liam and it's working fine.

```
aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name DataPipelineDefaultRole

aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile add-role-to-instance-profile --role-name DataPipelineDefaultRole --instance-profile-name DataPipelineDefaultRole
```

and there typo on the command provided should not repeat aws I am again.

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/add-role-to-instance-profile.html

Comment: `and there typo on the command provided should not repeat aws I am again` ??